# how to generate swagger document with tags using serverless-aws-documentation plugin for serverless

Tags: aws-lambda, swagger, serverless-framework

I am using serverless-aws-documentation plugin to auto-generate swagger-doc. Followed all the steps provided at : https://github.com/9cookies/serverless-aws-documentation. Under documentation key I am defining tags but it is not getting generated in the output swagger doc. Following is the sample handler :

```
functions:
  get_tickets:
    handler: handler.ticket_handler.get_tickets
    events:
      - http:
          path: tickets
          method: get
          cors: true
          documentation:
            tags:
              - private
              - admin
            summary: "Get list of ticket"
            description: "This ticket will provide you list of tickets"
```

I want to segrigate APIs depending on the tags, but not able to achieve it. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the `serverless-aws-documentation` plugin in the serverless.yml

```
plugins:
  - serverless-aws-documentation
```

Add the infor and models documentation in the custom section:

```
custom:
  myStage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  profiles:
    dev: road-we-go
    prod: road-we-
  documentation:
    info:
      version: "1.0.0"
      name: "Example API"
      description: "Example API description"
      termsOfService: "https://example.com/terms-of-service"
      contact:
        name: "Example API"
        url: "https://example.com"
        email: "dev@example.com"
      licence:
        name: "Licensing"
        url: "https://example.com/licensing"
    models:
      -
        name: "StoreAudioSuccess"
        description: "Model for store audio"
        contentType: "application/json"
        schema: ${file(swagger/audios/storeResponse.
```

Add the function documentation:

> If you want to add the custom models like `RequestStore` and `StoreAudioSuccess` check the `serverless-aws-documentation` [documentation](https://github.com/deliveryhero/serverless-aws-documentation) and the `json-schema` [docs](https://json-schema.org/)

```
functions:
  Update:
    handler: src/functions/update.handler
    timeout: 30
    memory: 128
    events:
      - http:
         method: put
         private: true
         cors: true
         path: api/v1/update
         documentation:
           summary: "Update "
           description: "Update a record"
           tags:
             - "Users"
           requestModels:
              "application/json": "RequestStore"
           methodResponses:
             -
              statusCode: "200"
              responseModels:
                 "application/json": "StoreUserSuccess"
```

To download the swagger documentation you need to run this command:

> First you need to deploy you project

```
sls downloadDocumentation --outputFileName=swagger.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using?

According to their latest documentation https://github.com/9cookies/serverless-aws-documentation, you need to provide tags as follows i.e. within double quotes.

```
documentation:
    tags:
      - "private"
      - "admin"
```

Comment: Did it worked? I still unable to get the tags on the Swagger file...