# How to document Node typescript AWS serverless API?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, documentation, serverless

My team is working on a new API using the [Serverless](https://www.serverless.com/) aws-nodejs-typescript template.

In previous APIs we've used the [aws](https://github.com/deliveryhero/serverless-aws-documentation) or [openAPI](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-openapi-documentation) plugin for Serverless in order to document our APIs. However, we find it cumbersome since it requires an extra effort after development and implementation. Also it might become outdated whenever the team drops the bar regarding keeping it up to date.

We would like to use some kind of annotations similar to springdoc-openapi-ui for Java. I've seen there exists a [Typescript Swagger package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-rest-swagger), however it seems to be right choice when not using Serverless(AWS) but for instance [Express](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction).

Has anyone used or found the right tooling to document Serverless AWS lambda APIs using Node and Typescript?

Any suggestion or hint will be more than welcomed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the plugin `serverless-aws-documentation` in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482657/how-to-generate-swagger-document-with-tags-using-serverless-aws-documentation-pl/58724099#58724099) I give an explanation of how to use it

Comment: As stated on the question description we've used it on previous projects but it is cumbersome. My current goal is not to document on the Serverless file but on the code itself. Anyway thanks for the hint.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question, if it is a long time and sometimes even annoying documenting our api, I have seen some colleagues who use Serverless with NestJS and from what they comment it is more comfortable because they do not have to generate models, etc etc, just coding, but I haven't really used it